# Soma da multiplicação da quantidade por valor do produto em vendas diarias

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho uma página de pedidos, vamos tomar como base um mercantil, onde a pessoa compra 3 refrigerantes cada um com o valor de R$6,00 e 2 biscoitos no valor de R$2,00 cada.

Primeiro preciso realizar a multiplicação desses valores (3 * 6) e (2 * 2) e depois somar seus resultados, o que daria um valor total da compra de R$22,00 bem como trazer o nome do cliente que fez a compra.

Estou usando o Eloquent do Laravel, mas venho encontrando algumas dificuldades na elaboração da query, se puderem me ajudar, segue o código e a imagem do relacionamento

```
$vendas = Venda::where('data', date('Y-d-m'))
        ->join('clientes', 'vendas.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
        ->join('produtos_venda', 'vendas.id', '=', 'produtos_venda.venda_id')
        ->select('vendas.*', 'clientes.nome as nome_cliente', 'produtos_venda.quantidade', 'produtos_venda.valor')
        ->sum('produtos_venda.valor * produtos_venda.quantidade as valor_total')->get();
```

[image: Relacionamento das tabelas]

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: receber somente o nome do cliente, data da venda e o valor total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira correta seria:

```
$select = "sum(produtos_venda.valor*produtos_venda.quantidade) as total,";
$select .= "vendas.cliente_id, clientes.nome, vendas.data";

$vendas = Venda::where('data', date('Y-d-m'))
        ->join('clientes', 'vendas.cliente_id', '=', 'clientes.id')
        ->join('produtos_venda', 'vendas.id', '=', 'produtos_venda.venda_id')
        ->groupBy('vendas.cliente_id', 'clientes.nome', 'vendas.data')
        ->select(\DB::raw($select))
        ->get();
```

<sub>***Observações:***</sub>

- Na tabela produto, mudo o tipo do campo `preco` para `decimal(10,2)`
- Na tabela vendas, mudo o tipo do campo `data` pra `date`
- Na tabela de produtos_vendas mudo o tipo do campo valor para `decimal(10,2)`
- Se por ventura achar que `decimal(10,2)`, seja insuficiente aumente o número 10 para 12

*Essas observações podem e devem ser seguidas, se tem o tipo correspondente porque utilizar um tipo que pode atrapalhar inclusive nas operações de soma, multiplicação, etc e filtros com datas, então, sempre coloque os tipos correspondentes.*

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Laravel - queries#selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#selects)
- [Laravel - Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: Valeu cara!! Deu certinho aqui